# Conditional view contribution with vscode extension api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to show my view contribution only when the editor has an HTML file. According to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28325), I can use the `when` clause. I found [in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#controlling-when-a-command-shows-up-in-the-command-palette) an example for a file type based condition. It's used on a command and not on a view contribution though.

I am trying with the below config, the view contribution is hidden but doesn't show up when I open an HTML file. If I remove the when clause, the view contribution shows fine but of course all the time.

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:html"
],
"contributes": {
    "views": {
    "explorer": [
        {
          "id": "documentOutline",
          "name": "Document Outline",
          "when": "editorLangId == html"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [contributes.views](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.views) documentation the `when` depends on **context** values.

And according to the npm extension it can also contain config settings.

```json
    "views": {
      "explorer": [{
        "id": "npm",
        "name": "%view.name%",
        "when": "npm:showScriptExplorer || config.npm.enableScriptExplorer"
      }]
    },
```

The npm extension sets a context value in the activation function

```js
    if (await hasPackageJson()) {
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'npm:showScriptExplorer', true);
    }
```

You might try the following:

In your extension define an event handler to get called when the editor changes (`onDidChangeActiveTextEditor`).

In the event handler set the context value based on the langugeId of the document.

**Edit**

It works with the following code

```
  const setContext = () => {
      vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'documentOutline:fileIsHTML',
          vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.languageId == 'html'); };
  vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(setContext, null, context.subscriptions);
  setContext();
```

And in the `package.json`

```json
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:html"
],
"contributes": {
    "views": {
    "explorer": [
        {
          "id": "documentOutline",
          "name": "Document Outline",
          "when": "documentOutline:fileIsHTML"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

---

Or looking at this issue [conditional visibility for custom views](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/29436) it might be even simpler. See Weinands example: add quotes in the `==` compare.

```json
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:html"
],
"contributes": {
    "views": {
    "explorer": [
        {
          "id": "documentOutline",
          "name": "Document Outline",
          "when": "editorLangId == 'html'"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Tried this and it does not work, maybe `editorLangId` is not a context variable.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked the context completely and was already wondering where they get the values from the use for the conditionals. Setting some context boolean and checking against that works perfect.